# How to simplify this UNION query (remove the UNION)?

Tags: postgresql, select, optimization, lazy-loading, jpql

I have a table with players, let's call it `player`.

Let's say they have 3 columns: `userId` (`UUID in a varchar(255)`), `levelNumber` (`integer`) and a column through a one-to-one relation with `FetchType.Lazy`, let's say `facebookProfile`.

I need to retrieve the rankings "around" the player, so 9 players above the given player and 9 players below the given player, to have a total of 19 players (with my player in the middle).

Some time ago I just came up with this idea:

```
(select * from player where current_level >= :levelNumber + 1 and (not userid = :userIdToIgnore) order by current_level asc limit 9)
union
(select * from player where  current_level <= :levelNumber - 1 and (not userid = :userIdToIgnore) order by current_level desc limit 9)
```

You get the idea.

**Is there any way to simplify this so it doesn't use the UNION?**
I'm asking cause I need to convert that to a `JPQL` query, so it won't be a `nativeQuery`.
This is all because `nativeQueries` lead to the `N+1` problem and I have troubles with lazy-loading (facebookProfile column) and multiple selects later. That's why I need to simplify that algorithm to be able to use JPQL.

Comment: I want to remove the union and make it either one select, select with joins or select with a subselect. Anything that will work with JPQL since UNIONS are not supported in JPQL.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this with window functions and conditional expressions:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*, 
        case when current_level >= :levelNumber + 1 then row_number() over(order by current_level)      end rn1, 
        case when current_level <= :levelNumber - 1 then row_number() over(order by current_level desc) end rn_desc
    from player p
    where userid <> :userIdToIgnore and (current_level >= :levelNumber + 1 or current_level <= :levelNumber - 1)
) t
where rn1 between 1 and 9 or rn2 between 1 and 9
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if that can be expressed in JPQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have no knowledge at all about JPQL so I'll trust you on this. I worked under OP's comment: *either one select, select with joins or select with a subselect*.

Comment: To my knowledge JPQL is limited to the most basic SQL:92 things (excluding UNIONs ;) ). It does not support any of the modern SQL features.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll just split it all to 2 separate queries :D Thanks guys for taking the time!